# No repository found during checking Eclipse updates

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse 3.7.2

Run `help -> Check for Updates`, Eclipse pops up `Problem occurred` window below,

```
Contacting sofware sites has encountered a problem.
No repository found at file:///tmp/formic_xxxxxx/update.
```

Processing stops after confirmation. How to solve it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At that location specified by the URL, it expects to see a `content.xml` and `artifact.xml` file along with the plugins and possibly other files. Those files are not likely present at that URL.

Either fix or remove the URL (in the *Preferences* → *Install/Update* → *Available Software Sites*).

Comment: But the error doesn't indicate which URL location has encountered the problem. How to find out?

Comment: Am I missing something? Your error message says "No respository found at: file:///tmp/formic_xxxxxx/update", that's the URL.

Comment: Thanks. It's me who misunderstood. i had thought that it must have been a remote repository. BTW, the problematic local URL refers to the location ${p2.metadata.repo.name}, what's it?

Comment: That's the URL that contains the files that I mention in my answer. That variable is used in the Ant scripts that build products and plugins.

Comment: Would Eclipse own updates never go through if i simply disable this problematic local URL to allow other updates to work out?

Comment: They should be fine, and even if this URL is still there, it should normally not interfere with updates. It will give this message and just ignore it; it will still check everything else. Maybe in your case, there was nothing to update.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too.
It seemed the Eclipse updater only works with a trailing "/" for repositories that don't explicitly point to a file.

E.g.

- OK: http://emonic.sourceforge.net/updatesite/nchc/site.xml
- OK: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/
- NOT OK: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

[Check here for instruction. Thanks to Devon.](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/no-repository-found-containing-error-when-update-eclipse.html/comment-page-1#comment-215287)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem. Not just one, but well past a dozen repositories 'not found.' Tried a few other things, but the "the Eclipse updater only works with a trailing "/" for repositories that don't explicitly point to a file." solution worked for me.

Note: explicitly using the 'Edit...' button didn't work. As soon as a "/" is added, it warns about "duplicate entry" and disables the 'Update' control.

Instead, selected all the 'eclipse' -related items, did 'export' to a file, closed eclipse, then edited the file in UltraEdit, as specified, then 'import'ed the file. After this, the update worked.

Comment: why these updates (eclipse and Android's too) have so many flow problems in their update processes tells me the developers of these two sets of packages aren't using these methods. I wonder what they use.

eclipse Indigo 2012, apparently now mostly Feb 2012 through Apr 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when switching to the new release candidate of mars. None of the above mentioned solutions did work for me. If anyone should be trapped with the same issue, I finally succeded with the following:

Deleting the **`.eclipse`** and **`.p2`** folders in my **`C:\Users\[my user]\`** folder.

After that I also "reinstalled" eclipse which might not even be necessary.

Comment: when I did `rm -rf ~/.eclipse/ ~/.p2`, the eclipse4.10 refused to run giving an error box `cannot find companion shared library', and the `eclipse/eclipse` executable gave an stdout message `/home/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.900.v20180922-1751: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. However Eclipse 4.8.0 aka Photon Release ran okay.