# Eclipse neon Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) error message

Tags: eclipse, ide

Eclipse Neon Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500
constantly gives out error message after searching of updates:

No repository found at http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/neon/4.4.0.Final.html.

What could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error seems a lot like this one here: [No repository found during checking Eclipse updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749995/no-repository-found-during-checking-eclipse-updates)

> At that location specified by the URL, it expects to see a content.xml
>   and artifact.xml file along with the plugins and possibly other files.
>   Those files are not likely present at that URL.
>
> Either fix or remove the URL (in the Preferences → Install/Update →
>   Available Software Sites).